# Matlab curve fitting a set of 2D points

Tags: matlab

Currently I have a set of 2D points as shown below.
[image: Random 2D points]

I need to obtain fitted curve of the points to determine the shape of the object.

Matlab offers a [spline fitting function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13812-splinefit). I have to applied it to the set of points. However, the results I am obtaining is shown below.[image: spline fit].

```
         xx = linspace(-10,10,20);
         pp2 = splinefit(PV(:,1),PV(:,2),8,5);
         y2 = ppval(pp2,xx);

         plot(x,y,'.',xx,y2), grid on
         axis([-10 10 -10 10]);
```

PV is the data points. I am unsure where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fit `PV(:,1) = f( PV(:,2) )` that is, fitting *directly* `y=f(x)`. But as you can see from your points, there are multiple values of `y` for certain values of `x` (around `x=0` and `x=-15`). Thus, you cannot **mathematically** fit `y=f(x)` for any function `f(.)` here.

What you can do is fit a parametric curve using an auxiliary parameter `t`:

```
t = linspace(0, 1, size(PV,1));
ppx = splinefit(PV(:,1),t,8,5);  % x = f_x(t)
ppy = splinefit(PV(:,2),t,8,5);  % y = f_y(t)
```

Now you can plot the curve `(f_x(t), f_y(t))`:

```
tt = linspace(0, 1, 50);
x2 = ppval(ppx, tt);
y2 = ppval(ppy, tt);
plot( PV(:,1), PV(:,2), '.', x2, y2); grid on;
axis([-10 10 -10 10]);
```

**Note**:
This fitting scheme is based on the assumption that the points in `PV` are *ordered*: That is, the curve should follow from `PV(1,:)` to `PV(2,:)` and then to `PV(3,:)` and so on. If this is not the case (e.g., `PV(1,:)` has x value of ~-10, `PV(2,:)` has x value of ~0 and `PV(3,:)` jumps back to x ~-10) then you are in deep s&#t.

Comment: how can one achieve the same results if the points are un ordered?

Comment: @Sade deep s&#t as I already said. You need to order them, otherwise the fitting is meaningless. Think about a [connect the dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_the_dots) where someone shuffled the dots' numbers at random... you are not going to get the desired output...